# Entity Framework self referencing

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the entities User and BlockedUser. A User has many BlockedUsers. BlockedUsers is a list of Users that are blocked by the User. How can I implemented these classes using Code First? After the database is created. There is no trace of the BlockedUser in the User table.

```
public class User : IdentityUse
{
    public List<User> BlockedUser;
}
```

Comment: You have a `User` with a `List<Users>` which are the blocked users.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But is that enought?

Comment: Try it and see. Then if you have a problem post your code and explain what you expected it to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: What do you mean by *A `User` has many blocked users*. If `BlockedUsers` is a list of users blocked by the containing `User`, then why would you have many `BlockUsers` instead of a single list ?

Comment: One User can Block many other Users.

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. Is there a problem with the code you've provided? If you want a more general review of your solution, perhaps try Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Michael I'll make the question more specific.

Comment: *After the database is created. There is no trace of the BlockedUser in the User table.* Well, there should be self-referencing foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ef database first so I first created tables like below.you have many to many relationship.

```
create table User
(
ID int primary key,
Name nvarchar(100),
)
create table BlockedUsers
(
UserID int,
BlockUserID int,
primary key( UserID, BlockUserID),
foreign key ( UserID) references User(ID),
foreign key ( BlockUserID) references User(ID),
)
```

YOU CAN create table then create model from that

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a trace of BlockedUser in the User table. It will create a BlockedUser table which will have a foreign key back to the User table. So you might have five rows in the BlockedUser table eventually, all referring back to User with ID 1. When you navigate to BlockedUsers via the List property on User, EF will load the BlockedUsers for you.

You should create the List property with the virtual keyword if you want lazy-loading of BlockedUsers.

Comment: There is no BlockedUser tabel.

Comment: @AmirRezaei Have you added BlockedUser to the context as a DbSet?

Comment: Paul there is no BlockTabel in Server Explorer for the database.